# NSString boundingRectWithSize bugged on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, nsstring, ios9

I have run into a definite issue with NSString and boundingRectWithSize.

On an iOS 8 iPhone, everything is sound and well. It calculates the correct size of a string when rendered with a font at a certain size.
With a iOS 9 GM seed iPhone, the width is always maxed out at 320, consistently. If the string is short, below 320 points, that will be correctly and consistently reported as on an iOS 8 device, but when an iOS 8 device reports a width beyond 320, the iOS 9 device always reports a width of 320.

The app is compiled using Xcode 6.4, ie using iOS 8 SDK. The OS I use is OS X El Capitan GM seed. I have *heard*, that using Xcode 6 on El Capitan is not really recommended. The recommended version of Xcode for El Capitan is Xcode 7. I cannot use Xcode 7 yet (but will try it shortly, just to try...) because of business reasons.
**UPDATE: I just tried compiling using Xcode 7 and SDK 9.0 - the widths are still maxed out at 320. The Xcode and/or SDK version is not the issue. iOS 9.0 is either bugged here or just behaves differently ;-)**

Anyone ran into the issue?
If I find no one else, I guess I will report this bug (I suspect it is a bug. Or just inconsistent behaviour which I really don't think Apple meant without giving some kind of deprecation warning) to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution, or answer if you will.

I don't think there is a bug in iOS 9, it just behaves differently, and from what I understand, more correct, than iOS 8. So yes, inconsistent, but better...

The size I fed to boundingRectWithSize: was always set to like 320x30ish. On iOS8 this function happily ignored the max width there and returned sizes above that, above 320 in my case. iOS 9 however correctly does not return sizes beyond that max size.
So I just changed the maxsize to `CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, 30)` and now iOS 8 and 9 seem to both report the same sizes even beyond 320. Case closed.

Comment: I am using boundingRectWithSize for iOS 8 and iOS 9 for lengthy text for smaller frame size (100,100).
IOS 8 returns size as 0 and iOS 9 returns actual size. Is there any particular reason for this behavior